# How to identify the clicked shape name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an excel template where I have already assigned different macros to different shape that act as buttons. Now I am having problem of locating which one I have clicked since I need to modify the attributes of the clicked shape after clicking on that shape. While searching on this problem, I have noticed that there is a way to identify which shape has been selected whereas I still doesn't know **How to get the name of the shape I have clicked or is there a way to refer to that clicked shape in VBA**? Thank you!

Comment: So pick an answer!

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to get the name of the clicked shape by using `Application.Caller`

usage as shown

```
 CallingShapeName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name 

 msgbox CallingShapeName
```

Comment: What? `Application.Caller` is the name of the clicked shape already? lol Main thing to show here is that you can get a reference to the shape object from the `Application.Caller`

Comment: @Sancarn What do you mean?

Comment: @Davesexcel I've made an edit to the supplied answer. `Application.Caller` in this instance, already contains a shape. So `msgbox Application.Caller.Name` is what you should do. Not `msgbox ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller.Name).Name`. The code using `ActiveSheet` may also obtain the wrong shape reference in very special circumstances.

Comment: For me `Application.Caller`  returned the shape name. `Application.Caller.Name` failed.

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

Comment: Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) from StackOverflow Help.

Comment: I have a SHAPE with Macro Assigned... Inside the Macro (aka Sub), I was able to use:     
`txtShapeText = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text`

Answer (score 0):

This suffices:

```
Msgbox Application.Caller
```