# Reference multiple shapes on click

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a slide with 3 shapes: A, B a C. I need to set C visible if A was clicked and invisible if B was clicked. I was looking for a way to get the ID of the shape that was clicked, but it looks like that's not possible ([here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/powerpoint-shape-click-event/a3a8158c-f87b-44a9-b28e-41873667d91b) and [it looks like you can do it in Excel but this does not work in powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763629/how-to-identify-the-clicked-shape-name-in-vba)).

I have also tried using the following:

```
Sub test(oSh As Shape)
    Dim thisSlideNum As Long
    thisSlideNbr = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.slide.SlideIndex

    Select Case oSh.Name
        Case "A"
            ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.slide.Shapes([ID of C]).Visible = 0

    End Select

End Sub
```

However, this does not work. I have also tried, the same with the line

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes([ID of C]).Visible = 1
```

This also does not do anything. I've verified that the case statement is True. Does someone know the right syntax to change the visibility of a shape based on which other shape was clicked?

Comment: Is this in Windows or Mac PowerPoint? It matters.  And also, have you given your shape a Run Macro action setting and had it run your Test subroutine?

Comment: Q1: Windows. Q2: I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version that does work. Changes:

Since the sub is passed a reference to the clicked shape, you can get a reference to the slide using oSh.Parent, which eliminates some complexity.

I've changed the shape names and made sure they're correct and referenced the shapes by name. IIRC you can't directly reference shapes by ID, only by name or Index. Granted, there can be value in using the shape's ID, but you'd need to write a FindShapeByID function yourself to do so.

```
Sub test(oSh As Shape)

    Select Case oSh.Name
        Case "Rectangle 5"
            oSh.Parent.Shapes("Rectangle 7").Visible = True
        Case "Rectangle 6"
            oSh.Parent.Shapes("Rectangle 7").Visible = False
    End Select

End Sub
```